# High-quality hero images get blurry when viewed at smaller sizes

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, highdpi

I've been trying to fix an issue where the full-width hero images on my Wordpress website appear blurry on some mobile devices, and in the process I've noticed that this seems to be triggered only at smaller sizes.

The images I'm using are 1920 x 1080 pixels.

**Between a width of 1920px to 1024px** the images look high-quality and unchanged as far as I can tell, but using Firefox's Responsive Design Mode, I've established that the smaller the image renders the more progressively blurrier (i.e. pixellated) it becomes.

If the browser window is resized to a width of **1023px or less**, it becomes a *little* blurry, whereby setting the DPR setting to **2** restores it to the original quality.

If the browser window is resized to a width of **512px or less**, the image becomes *very* blurry, and setting the DPR to **3** restores it to the original quality.

What's going on here? I understand that the images aren't Retina-optimised, but if this was the actual cause, wouldn't the problem be reversed - wouldn't it be the *larger* image size that would render blurry? Shouldn't the smallest image render at a high DPI considering it's being displayed at a size of 512px and the source image is much less than double (2x) the 1920px source image?

Would really appreciate some help figuring this out as I've been struggling with it for a few days and it's very hard to test against and debug.

Comment: If the same problem exists on a real device, post some code so we can try to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

A HiDPI image is really just one that's larger than the display size but crushed into a smaller physical space.

For example if your 1x image is 500px x 500px, then a 2x image would be 1000px x 1000px and 3x would be 1500px x 1500px. The HiDPI designation comes in because the device is able to display all those extra pixels in the same physical space as a normal screen.

So imagine a normal screen is 100px per 1 inch. So your 500px image would be 5in x 5in. The HiDPI screen might be 200px per 1 inch of screen so the 1000px image would still take up 5 inches.

Typically smaller images get blury on HiDPI displays because they're trying to "up res" something like a 500px x 500px image to a display size of 1500px x 1500px.

---

As for the problem you're experiencing, have you verified the issue on a real device not the FF emulator? Real devices are usually much better at that "up res" process and may not produce the same artifacts.